# Check if directory exists in my connected phone C#

Tags: c#, iphone, directory

When I plug in my iphone, I can access a folder named DCIM.

The file path is "This PC\Will-iPhone\Internal Storage\DCIM".

My question is how can I check to see if that folder exists? I need to know the way to check but not on a phone as it doesn't have C\ or H\ or whatever at the beginning of its file path.

Apparently, I cannot upload an image, but its just listed under devices and drivers as "Will-iPhone".

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"\\Will-iPhone\Internal Storage\DCIM\"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Yes");
        }
```

I've also tried with different amount of backslashes, having "This PC" at the start but nothing seems to work so far

Any help is appreciated. preferably C# btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iPhone (and other cameras) are so-called [PTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol) devices and are not accessible using UNC paths. Instead, you would need to implement PTP yourself or find a suitable library (which might be hard according to a quick Google search).

Other than that, there is [PTPdrive](http://www.ptpdrive.com/) (no affiliation) which allegedly maps PTP devices to a drive letter.

**Addendum**: after all, iPhones can be accessed using WIA, so I jotted this (add a COM reference to *Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition Library v2.0* to use):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using WIA;

public static class WiaCopy
{
    public static IEnumerable<IDeviceInfo> GetAppleDevices()
    {
        return new DeviceManager().DeviceInfos.Cast<IDeviceInfo>().Where(di =>
            di.Type == WiaDeviceType.CameraDeviceType
            && di.Properties["Manufacturer"].get_Value() == "Apple Inc."
            && di.Properties["Description"].get_Value() == "Apple iPhone");
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Item> GetImgItems(IDeviceInfo deviceInfo)
    {
        var device = deviceInfo.Connect();
        return device.Items.Cast<Item>().Where(i => i.Properties["Item Name"].get_Value().ToString().StartsWith("IMG"));
    }

    public static void TransferItem(Item item, string path)
    {
        // TODO: should use .mov for videos here
        var targetName = item.Properties["Item Name"].get_Value() + ".jpg";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        item.Transfer().SaveFile(Path.Combine(path, targetName));
    }
}
```

which can be used like so:

```
var savePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), "Auto Import");

foreach (var iPhone in WiaCopy.GetAppleDevices())
{
    foreach (var imgItem in WiaCopy.GetImgItems(iPhone))
    {
        WiaCopy.TransferItem(imgItem, Path.Combine(savePath, iPhone.Properties["Name"].get_Value()));
    }
}
```

Note that this works for images only, for videos (although these start with IMG too), if found no way to copy them using WIA. For starters, the above should suffice.

Comment: Thanks, i think thats the end of the road for me then. I cant use PTPdrive as i want it to work for all iphones. Im not that good at programming the first way you said sounds alot harder than its worth

Comment: Just realized you didn't want to copy the files... do you still find the answer useful?

Comment: can you explain how i can use WIA, i would like to test to see if the code works for me but i cant add "Using WIA;" and im not sure what to add COM to like you said. Im not that experienced with coding and im also using net framework 3.5 so it works on windows xp. thanks for the help

Comment: You should be able to right-click the project in VisualStudio, `Add -> Reference... -> COM -> Type Libraries` then search for `Image` (for me this returns 3 hits). Add *Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition Library v2.0*

Comment: Got it, thanks very much for your help so far. I put in the code and have got 2 errors. I cant uploads images but here they are...

item.Transfer().SaveFile(Path.Combine(path, targetName)); - the "savefile" is underlined in red and says that object doesnt contain a definition for savefile

the next one is...
Path.Combine(savePath, iPhone.Properties["Name"].get_Value())); - which just said it has invalid arguments. again excuse my ignorance, im not the best at programming

Comment: You can have a look at the sources on [GitHub](https://github.com/rasch/SO/tree/master/WiaCopyTool)

Comment: ah the errors appear because im using net framework 3.5, i tried on 4.5 and works perfectly. now i know its the framework i can fix that later.

Would this work for android phones too if i copy the code again just replace the model and manufacture in the code? also changing thew "startswith IMG as its different for andoid". thanks for all the help too, not many people would help someone this much :)

Comment: Yes, I guess it should work as well. But I do not have an Android phone to test. AFAIK most Android phones also have an operating mode where the phone is treated like an USB stick, so "normal" copying should work if they are set to this mode.

Comment: perfect i have one i can mess about with, thank again for all your help

Comment: if you have trouble converting to 3.5, see [this commit](https://github.com/rasch/SO/commit/910d0aa34bad7ed7443f27c1bde762a6fd7f2b01)

Answer (score 0):

check properties of `DCIM` folder there should be the full path.

Comment: i did that, it says "This PC\Will-iPhone\Internal Storage"