# Access iPhone picture files without iTunes and iCloud

Tags: ios, iphone, usb, file-transfer, ios14

I take pictures every day with my *iPhone S5* (iOS 14) and would like to store them in a day-wise directory on my *Windows 10* PC.

To transfer the picture files from *iPhone* to PC, I use an *USB* cable connection, allow *USB* access on the *iPhone* and then copy the picture files using *Windows Explorer*.

The *Explorer* shows something like the following:

[image]

To automate the process, I tried to get the directory path, a home-grown utility tool could use to copy the picture files directly without my intervention.

I used the following *C#* routine to get to know the current path of *Windows Explorer*:

```
private void ShowWindows()
{
    textBox1.Clear();

    foreach (IWebBrowser2 window in new ShellWindows())
    {
        textBox1.AppendText($"{window.LocationURL}\r\n");
    }
}
```

This works for *normal paths* on my SSD. But the *iPhone* paths appear to be different. I don't get any information about them. In *Windows Explorer*, there is no property dialog for these *iPhone* directories. I looked through the [Windows CLSID list](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3123-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-10-a.html), but this did not help either.

How can I programatically copy *iPhone* picture files like normal *USB* flash drive files?
Or is it unavoidable to resort to special tools like *iTunes*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that phones do not get mounted to the filesytem and do not get thier drive letter. Explorer communicates with them using WIA protocol. So you will need to write separate code to deal with images from iPhone.

You can find documentaton is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wia/-wia-wia-tutorial

Comment: A [WIA example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31905301/1911064) was posted several years ago. But thank you anyhow.